# Regular Expressions on PHP remove url from an email string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match-all

I'm uploading Tab Delimited text files exported from Excel, basically i'm getting all email fields on the document, by using a preg_match_all

```
preg_match_all("/([\s]*)[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+@[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+/i",$string,$emails);
```

In some cases emails are saved with a url attached to it like this: `prefix.user@domain.comwww.domain.com`

i need to strip only the email without the url that's afterwards the email address

how can i make this work using regular expressions??

Comment: Not well... can you get your data-supplier to fix the files; it would save you a lot of bother in the longer run.

Comment: The data is from an 8 year-old excel contact directory there is like 200 files of it :S

Comment: Well putting aside the arguable pattern, it's part `@[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+` cannot possibly catch @domain.comwww.domain.com unless it is present as is in the input. And `domain.comwww.domain.com` is a legal domain in .com zone. Do all of your "false" captures look like "domain-without-www-followed-by-domain-with-www"?

Comment: No, there is like a 15% of the input with the url attached, i've done some tests with 10 different files and this anomaly is present in all of them, what i notice is that every url starts with www. but... dont know if there is some with http or https too... which i believe there are

Comment: i'm thinking on exploding the regex result into 2 strings one with the actual email and the other with the junk

Comment: Is your task to extract emails once and ditch the excel files? If so, manual walkthrough and fixing each erroneous pattern would be ok - it would be way easier than inventing AI to decide which email is ok)

Comment: Well my job is to create a simple tool that allows users to upload a txt file with bunch of contact info and get only the emails for their newsletter database, they will still using excel as a db engine, why? don't know but they don't want to do that kind of work,.. 

i've exploded the string this works for now, until i find a much aesthetic approach with regex

Answer (score 1):

List all possible domain names in last regexp group like this, including top-level domains by default.

```
[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|edu|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|asia|jobs|museum)
```

You can read more about *email validation* [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) or read the related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address).

**UPDATE**

Expression conforming to *[RFC 2822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt)* standard

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+(?:[a-zA-Z]{2}|com|org|net|edu|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|asia|jobs|museum)
```

Comment: Probably not, `a@co` is a valid e-mail address, you'll also be wrong on things like `a@b.com.au`...

Comment: i tried your updated regex and drops me a Unknown modifier '+'

Comment: @IvanBravoCarlos, strange, bec. I've checked it http://myregexp.com/ and it works well. Also tried http://regexpal.com/ and also Ok. Are you sure, you are doing everything right?